# How to connect to a client in Broadband shared IP

Tags: c, sockets, ip, connect, shared

I am using a Broadband Router on which multiple pcs use the same shared ip as the public ip. how can some other remote client get a specific IP address to connect to me?
I was developing a Client/Server Chat Program using C.

Thanks for considering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They cannot. The broadband router is the only one with a public IP address.

The usual solution to this problem is to have the router forward a specific port to one of your NAT'd internal machines.

If that's not sufficient, you could investigate "hole punching" and [STUN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN).

Comment: Can you tell me how to do the port forwarding?